# PiShrink creating files with different sizes with the same input

Tags: image, backup

I've recently started using PiShrink to decrease the size of backup images and I noticed that the file size of an with PiShrink shrunken and xz compressed image

```
sudo pishrink.sh -Z input_image.img shrunken_compressed.img
```

differs if I repeat it with the same input image.

But in comparison to that if I only shrink the image with PiShrink and then manually compress it with xz

```
sudo pishrink.sh input_image.img shrunken_compressed.img
sudo xz -z -k shrunken_compressed.img
```

it's always the same size.
Shouldn't PiShrink always produce the same result with the same input?
Does someone know the reason why that's not the case?